# Link Snowflake account to a AWS account id

Tags: amazon-web-services, account

i have a 30 day free trail Snowflake account. I am accessing a dataset [Covid-19 starschema] in this . The need now is to map the underlying AWS instance with a AWS account id which i already have. I want to avoid overrunning the credits available and would want the billing to be linked to my AWS account id. Any guidance on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the region your AWS Account is hosted in you can potentially use [AWS Marketplace to link your Snowflake account](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile?id=18d60ae8-2c99-4881-a31a-e74770d70347) to your AWS billing.

Additionally, unless you have contacted Snowflake directly, to organize a different arrangement, typically the free trial period credits will run out and any snowflake activity halted when used up, you won't be charged for any additional usage.

Comment: Thankyou for the response. How to decide which Snowflake product will be the best and should I directly subscribe to it in the AWS account?. Also how do I get the covid star schema dataset into this instance.

Comment: Start with the most basic snowflake product, try the features / capability etc out and see if the performance meets your needs. Without knowing your requirements its impossible for me to say which product you should get (your also better off talking with a Snowflake Sales Rep). As for the dateset is entirely dependent  on how star schema has set it up. It could be a user pays model or free model, you'd need to read the offering. There is quite a lot of documentation on their website around cross sharing in snowflake.